# Findings solutions to a modular equation within specified intervals

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What are some approaches to find (ideally many/all) pairs of numbers $(x, y)$  with $ x \in [x_{\text{low}}, x_{\text{high}}]$ and $ y \in [y_{\text{low}}, y_{\text{high}}]$ such that the following holds:

$$a \cdot x \equiv y \pmod{m}$$

- Exhaustive search is not feasible since the intervals are each greater than $10^{30}$.
- $m$ is not necessarily prime.

Edit: added a numerical example:

m=100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

a=25392686019781782164356679796166612429399009942400218996555274144660682152509428039692348610084264596008789972113702053939160192781697341

With $x \in [0, 10^{84}]$ and for convenience let's say that $y \in [y_0, y_0 + 10^{84}] $ with

y_0=33732319676131018538972274738642940983980721830265900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: It is not important how large your intervals are as long as they are in $mod m$, they are smaller than the main interval of $[0, m-1]$ since you are in $mod m$. As I have written in the answers, the extended Euclidean algorithm gives the efficient answer for $[0, m-1]$. You find at most $d$ answers in which $d=gcd(a,m)$. The time for checking that this $d$ numbers are in the given interval or not is independent of the size of your interval, it depends only on $d$ since they are $d$ numbers. This check is efficient too. So, this edit doesn't change the method.

Comment: BTW: are you asking this because you want to know how to do it, or are you asking whether this being hard would be a good security assumption?  For the former, I could go into more detail in my answer; the a latter, I believe my answer should be enough to show that it is not a good assumption

Comment: @m123  The main problem is that the intervals are very narrow, so it was not clear I can find any solution efficiently in my case where d=1.

Comment: @poncho I am asking because I want to know how to do it; it came up as part of a larger crypto problem and I was wondering whether there is any efficient route to finding solutions. I was also thinking something along the lines of LLL but couldn't find a valid reformulation of the problem, or maybe Integer Linear Programming but i wasn't able to determine if ILP would work since there is no software that can work with large numbers, only doubles or int64 values at most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem: convert it into a Lattice problem (where we have good tools)

That is, consider a two dimension lattice over $\mathbb{Z}$, with the basis vectors $(1, a)$ and $(0, m)$.  It is easy to verify that $(x, y)$ is a solution to $ax \equiv y \pmod m$ if and only if $(x, y) = c(1, a) + d(0, m)$ for integers $c, d$, that is, it is a point on the lattice.  And so, the restated problem is "what lattice points are in the rectangle $[x_{low}, y_{low}], [x_{high}, y_{high}]$"

Now, this basis is a bad basis; however we have an algorithm [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) which can take that bad basis and turn it into a much better basis $(u, v), (w, z)$.  In particular, these two basis vectors can't be closer that $60^\circ$ or greater than $120^\circ$ (otherwise LLL would find a smaller basis)

So, what we do is take the target rectangle $[x_{low}, y_{low}], [x_{high}, y_{high}]$ and transform that into our better basis, this will result in a parallelogram, with one corner being the value $(e, f)$ where $e(u, v) + f(w, z) = x_{low}, y_{low}$ (and note that $e, f$ are unlikely to be integers). And, this parallelogram has internal angles are not extreme; the angles will be between $60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$.

So then the problem comes in finding integral coordinates within that parallelogram; for each such one, we can map it back to the $(x, y)$ coordinates, which is a solution to the original problem.  This searching should be straightforward (given that the parallelogram is not extremely long and narrow)

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** This is not the right answer since I didn't consider $y$ as unkonwn here, but as I had written it and maybe others make the same mistake, I didn't delete it.

---

There are two cases:

1. $gcd(a,m)=1$
2. $gcd(a,m)=d>1$

solutions:

1. find s and t such that $as+mt=1$ (via extended Euclidean algorithm). Then put $a\equiv ys \mod m$. Check if the answer is in your interval, then accept or reject it.
2. if $d$ does not divide $y$, then there is no solution. otherwise, solve the congruence $a/d x \equiv y/d \mod m/d$ using 1. Consider the result as z. The answer of the main problem of $ax \equiv y \mod m$ are:

$z \mod m$

$z+ m/d\mod m$

$z+2m/d\mod m$

$...$

$z+(d-1)m/d \mod m$

Comment: I do not believe this is a correct answer to the question.  For one, (1) always finds a single solution to the modular equation (irresepective of the bounds); obviously, without the bounds, there are $m$ different solutions to that modular equation.

Comment: @poncho: But this is the efficient algorithm introduced in Trape and Washington's book for the same question without intervals. Checking each of the d answers to see if it is in the given interval or not (as I have written in bullet 1), do not change the complexity.
Additionally, without the intervals, there aren't $m$ different solutions, there are $d$ solutions.

Comment: If $as + mt = 1$ then $as + 0 \equiv 1 \pmod m $ so $s \equiv a^{-1} \pmod m$ . Setting $ a \equiv ys \pmod m$ implies $y \equiv a^2 \pmod m$ . Further, for (2), if we use the previous result and when $ d=1 $ then $ ax \equiv a^2 \pmod m$ so $ x \equiv a \pmod m$. 

What am I missing?

Comment: @fandreas: in the first case in which the gcd is 1, it is correct that $s≡a^{-1}(\mod m)$. I didn't get what you mean by "Setting a≡ys(modm)
 implies $y≡a^2(\mod m)$"
. and about your last sentence, the case $d=1$ is the first case, the second is for when you have $d>1$.

Comment: @m123: "Additionally, without the intervals, there aren't $m$
different solutions, there are $d$ solutions."; of course, there are $m$ solutions, there are $m$ possible values of $x$, and for each such value, there is exactly one value $y$ for which $ax = y \pmod m$

Comment: @poncho: Aha, I got what you mean. You mean both $x$ and $y$ are unknown here. I didn't consider $y$ as unkown. you are right.